# record / monitor asterisk incoming / outgoing calls on mp3

Tags: asterisk, recording

I am using vicidial based asterisk server 1.2 version. I want my asterisk server to **record** incoming and outgoing calls on **mp3** format rather than the default format **wav**.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Install sox and libsox-fmt-mp3, in Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-mp3
```

Put the command below in your crontab:

```
nice find /tmp -iname "*.wav" -type f -exec bash \ 
          -c 'WAV={}; MP3=${WAV/%wav/mp3}; sox -r 8000 -c 1 $WAV $MP3' \;
```

Comment: i am using centos 5 version.. would that be fine withe the script.. and can you also please kindly elaborate the what the above command does exactly.. I want play safe on my server and know what m about to do

Answer (score 0):

My solution for FreeBSD, one-time run the script, and then set up its periodical launch on the crontab:

```
#!/bin/sh

find /usr/asterisk/recording -name '*.wav' -type f -mmin +180 | while read filename; do
        nice -19 lame -h -v -b 32 "$filename" "${filename%.wav}.mp3" && touch -r "$filename" "${filename%.wav}.mp3" && rm "$filename"
done
```